# ETPS/2 Elan Touchpad Not Detected And not working

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-drivers, elantech, hp-touchpad

ELAN Touchpad not working for Hp pavilion 15-ec1073dx Touchpad No touchpad error and no response from xinput test, or xev.

Current kernel version 5.8.0. In Kernel 5.8 > Bluetooth does not work so I had to stick to 5.8.0.

When I add psmouse.proto=bare touchpad works but it's behaviour is disturbing and it is recognised as a PS/2 Mouse and nolonger ETPS/2 Elan(with xinput), and does not have any of the touch gestures functioning in this state. Also can not turn it off in Settings once registered as PS/2 Mouse. Tried a lot nothing works yet also purged synaptics.
I Installed synaptics tried it out, did not work out then purged it.

This is the working /etc/default/grub

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.proto=bare"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

This is my current /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Any other solutions would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to get the touchpad working but this method is somewhat not conventional.
1. Restore grub to it's original state 
```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""  
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```
2. update-grub
3. reboot
4. Press F9 and wait a few seconds (unclear of time frame)
5. Select Linux boot and touchpad should be recognized.

This only works for Hp Pavilion 15-e10xxx

Comment: try "modprobe i2c_hid",  have a look if it works. Here (https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207759) is a good way to get it working. I  have  problems w. ELAN, HID and  i2c devices on a Fujitsu E5510 (latest creation). Touchpad, Wifi and ethernet and keyboard did not start! Better result with Ubuntu 21.04(!).   What eventually helped in my case: Create a  Systemd service essentially invoking  "modprobe i2c_hid" . I can paste the code if someone wants. Plenty of tutorials for creating Systemd service out there.  Do not forget the "sudo systemctl enable" part!  FF!

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd> and wait a few seconds helps me but It doesn't save it on the next boot. And need again press <kbd>F9</kbd>. I don't know what the problem.