# What can I do to use the touchpad of my new laptop on Ubutntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, kernel, touchpad

My new laptop is HP OMEN 16 4080(2023 Released).And When I use the Ubuntu 20.04, its touchpad can not be detected.

```
wp@wp-OMEN:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G Pro                            id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Keychron Keychron K3                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keychron Keychron K3                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP True Vision FHD Camera: HP T           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP, Inc HyperX Wireless Audio Consumer Control    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G Pro                            id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keychron Keychron K3                      id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to switch to Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel v6.2.0.26 and the touchpad works indeed. Then I tried to upgrade the kernel of Ubuntu 20.04 from v5.19 to v6.2 and this touchpad also works well.It's certainly that the old kernel is not compatible with new hardware.

I have a project which needs to use ROS1(Robot operate system), so I can not use 22.04LTS recently.The method of upgrading kernel will lead to installation errors of NVIDIA drivers.
What should I do to make the OS be compatible with new hardware as well as use ROS1?

---

`lsusb` output

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:099c HP, Inc HyperX Wireless Audio 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0441 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP True Vision FHD Camera 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is there any plan for Canonical to upgrade the Linux kernal from v5.19 to v6.xx on Ubuntu 20.04.7 in the future?

Comment: Do you know whyt 22.04 isn't compatible with ROS1? I looked at [their repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/) and it seems that they skipped over Jammy. One solution might be to simply install the old repository on a newer version of ubuntu (install the focal repo on jammy) unless that causes some kind of conflict (dependency or compatibility issue).

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't be recommended because there could be all sorts of unknown bugs. If you're okay with that and it's not used for production like at work or something, then using the old repository might be an option but I wonder why they skipped over jammy and if there's a reason it's not included.

Comment: Two other options would be either compiling the ROS1 software from source on 22.04 or manually downloading the Nvidia driver from the Nvidia website on 20.04. On a side note, sometimes installing the synaptic touchpad software is necessary. So `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and then reboot. With this, you would need to make sure to log in using X11 instead of Wayland.

Comment: Also, it would help to include the output of `lsusb` and the version of your Nvidia device and driver version as well. With `lsusb` it should show us the exact device and manufacturer numbers which we can cross reference to search for solutions and also for compatible drivers that use these codes to identify the devices they apply to. It is likely that the driver was provided on its own in some form before it was included in the kernel.

Comment: I tried to compiling the ROS1 software from source on 22.04 but the dependency of each package makes me dizzy. I have installed  `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and my touchpad is from ELANTECH. The follow is the `lsusb` output, I I unplugged the external keyboard and external monitor to make the output look simple.

Comment: ```Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:099c HP, Inc HyperX Wireless Audio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0441 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP True Vision FHD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub```

Comment: Doesn't look like it's showing in `lsusb`. Try running `lspci -nn` and look for the line that appears to be the touchpad and then please post that line if it is listed. Also, if the synaptics package was already installed, then [sometimes uninstalling this package](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250843/) may get it to work but you would have to reboot afterwards. Also, the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` package may help if it's not already installed.

Comment: Also, according to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310101/etps-2-elan-touchpad-not-detected-and-not-working#comment2271872_1310101), try running `sudo modprobe i2c_hid` which makes sense as my chromebook ELAN toughpad uses the same driver iirc.

Comment: There's a couple of other things [mentioned in detail on the bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207759#c19). They also unbind the touchpad from another driver using an echo command but to run this in the terminal you would run `echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2c/unbind` and then to bind you would run `echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" | sudo tee /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/i2c_hid/bind` (because you need to use `sudo` and redirecting `sudo echo` using `>` will not work).

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem, have you found a solution?